Transcribing gregorian chants using MusixTeX: best strategies?
Which are the best strategies to transcribe gregorian chants in modern notation using MusixTeX? Specially, how could I address the following issues?

how to write "divisio minima" bars (quarter-height bars at the 5th line of the staff) and "divisio minor" bars (half-height bars centered in the staff)?
how to write star/dagger symbols in lyrics and make them be aligned to bars?
which is the best strategy to make notes in a multi-note neum very close together (including slurs)?


Have you tried a combination of inputs (MusixTeX and Gregorio)? For the second: then could help page 101 of GregorioRef. For the third: you can scale, you could work with \rlap, you can work with non spacing notes en shift heads to the right or left. Try something and come back with a more specific problem.
